# [R3 Corda]Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.IOUContractnull

Tags: java, corda

When I run tutorial: `Hello, World!`

Pt.2 - Contract constraints I hava the error:

> Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.IOUContractnull.

I start from template and then finish helloword1. helloword1 run OK.

```
...build\nodes\PartyA\logs\node-clay-PC.log


--- Transition of flow [3d6b6d20-bc45-4e71-831a-b0cddd89b50d] ---
  Timestamp: 2019-07-02T11:57:54.562Z
  Event: Error(exception=net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.IOUContractnull. See https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging)
  Actions: 
    RollbackTransaction
    ScheduleEvent(event=DoRemainingWork)
  Continuation: ProcessEvents
  Diff between previous and next state:
checkpoint.errorState: 
    Clean
    Errored(errors=[FlowError(errorId=-9033011467502490789, exception=net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.IOUContractnull. See https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging)], propagatedIndex=0, propagating=false)
isFlowResumed: 
    true
    false
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer "Debugging" section of following documentation - 
https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html

Docs -

> If an attachment constraint cannot be resolved, a MissingContractAttachments exception is thrown. There are three common sources of MissingContractAttachments exceptions:
>
> 1. You are running a test and have not specified the CorDapp packages to scan.
> 2. When running the Corda node ensure all CordDapp JARs are placed in cordapps directory of each node
> 3. You are specifying the fully-qualified name of the contract incorrectly

In the logs the contract name is recorded as "com.template.***IOUContractnull***" instead of "com.template.***IOUContract***" --

```
Event: Error(exception=net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.IOUContractnull. See https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging)
```

Please check ID value in IOUContract class.

```
public class IOUContract implements Contract {
    public static final String ID = "com.template.IOUContract";
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to change it to:

```
public class IOUContract implements Contract {
    public static final String ID = "com.template.contracts.IOUContract";
```

I completed the tutorial in Kotlin and found that the following worked as well for setting the contract ID:

```
companion object {
    val ID = IOUContract::class.qualifiedName!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't add `implements Contract` in my contract class signature (which implements an interface that `extends Contract`). I just added the siginature and it worked fine.